# Python - Downloading PDFs from website behind dropdown

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

For the site https://www.wsop.com/tournaments/results/, the objective is to download all available PDFs on the REPORTS section, behind all different drop down options where they are available.

Currently I am trying to do this using selenium, because I couldn't find an api, but I am open to other suggestions. For now the code is a bunch of copy-paste from relevant questions and YT videos.

**My plan of attack is to select an option in the drop-down menu, press 'GO' (to load them), navigate to 'REPORTS' (if available) and download all the PDFs available. And then iterate over all options. Challenge 2 is then to get the PDFs to something like a dataframe to do some analysis.**

Below is my current code, that only manages to download the top PDF of the by default selected option in the drop-down:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#settings and loading webpage
options=Options()
options.headless=True
CD=ChromeDriverManager().install()

driver=webdriver.Chrome(CD,options=options)

params={'behavior':'allow','downloadPath':os.getcwd()+'\\PDFs'}
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.setDownloadBehavior',params)

driver.get('https://www.wsop.com/tournaments/results/')

#Go through the dropdown
drp=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("CPHbody_aid"))
drp.select_by_index(0)

drp=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("CPHbody_grid"))
drp.select_by_index(1)

drp=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("CPHbody_tid"))
drp.select_by_index(5)

#Click the necessary buttons (section with issues)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav-tabs"]/a[6]').click()

#driver.find_element_by_name('GO').click()
#WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "GO"))).click()

#WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "REPORTS"))).click()

a=driver.find_element_by_id("reports").click()
```

I can navigate through the drop-down just fine (and it should be easy to iterate over them). However, I do not get the 'GO' button pressed. I tried it a bunch of different ways, a few I showed as a comment in the code.

I am able to press the REPORTS tab, but I think that breaks down when there are different amounts of tabs, the line in the comments might work better, but for now I am not able to download all PDFs anyway, it just takes the first PDF of the page.

Many thanks to whoever can help:)

Comment: Please share the direct link of the website

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar What do you mean? The main website is www.wsop.com, the relevant section is https://www.wsop.com/tournaments/results/, as I shared in the text.

Comment: okay, it opened now. Tell me what exactly do you need. You just want to download all pdf from report section. that's all?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar Oh, missed your 2nd comment, sorry. Yes, I want to download all the PDFs for the different years and tournaments, so basically iterate through the CPH_grid and CPH_tid options and download all PDFs on the REPORTS section, if available (not for all tournaments they are available).

Answer (score 1):

The website is structured in such a way that you can loop through the years that a WSOP was played, then within each year you can loop through every event and get the data from page into a pandas dataframe. This is far more efficient than taking screenshots into PDFs

You can edit how far you want to go back with the `from_year` variable in line 5, going way back will obviously take more time. See the below script which will output all the data into csv. Note that not every event has POY points available. Also you'll need to pip install requests, pandas and bs4 if you haven't already.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from_year = 2020

wsop_tounrament_url = 'https://www.wsop.com/tournaments/GetTournaments.aspx?aid=2'
wsop_resp = requests.get(wsop_tounrament_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(wsop_resp.text,'html.parser')

years = [x['value'] for x in soup.find_all('option') if str(from_year) in x.text]

event_dfs = []
for year in years:
    event_resp = requests.get(f'https://www.wsop.com/tournaments/GetEvents.aspx?grid={str(year)}')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(event_resp.text,'html.parser')
    event_ids = [x['value'] for x in soup.find_all('option')]
    for event in event_ids:
        page = 1
        while True:
            url = f'https://www.wsop.com/tournaments/results/?aid=2&grid={year}&tid={event}&rr=5&curpage={page}'
            results = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text,'html.parser')

            info = soup.find('div',{'id':'eventinfo'})
            dates = info.find('p').text
            name = info.find('h1').text
            year_name = soup.find('div',{'class':'content'}).find('h3').text.strip()
            table = soup.find('div',{'id':'results'})

            size = int(table.find('ul')['class'][0][-1])
            rows = table.find_all('li')
            if len(rows) <= size+1:
                break
            print(f'processing {year_name} - {name} - page {page}')
            output = []
            headers = []
            for x in range(size):
                series = []
                for i, row in enumerate(rows):
                    if i == x:
                        headers.append(row.text)
                        continue
                    if i%size == x:
                        series.append(row.text)
                output.append(series)

            df = pd.DataFrame(output)
            df = df.transpose()
            df.columns = headers
            df['year_name'] = year_name
            df['event_id'] = event
            df['year_id'] = year
            df['event_name'] = name
            df['dates'] = dates
            df['url'] = url
            event_dfs.append(df)
            page += 1
    print(f'Scraped {year_name} successfully')

final_df = pd.concat(event_dfs)
final_df.to_csv('wsop_output.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am after the chip counts of players for the different days. I am trying to make an estimation of ROI for different players and plan to do this based on the increase in chips from day 1 to day 2 etc. on average. Or use the entry list as it is available for some older years. AFAIK this info is only in the PDF and not in the sites HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to write you the whole script but here's how to click on the "go" button :
We can see from the Developper tools that the button is the only element to have the class "submit-red-button", so we can access it with : `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('submit-red-button')[0].click()`

You say that you can access the Reports tab but it did not work when I tested your program so just in case, you can use `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('taboff')[4]` to get it.

Then, all you need to do is to click on each pdf link in order to download the files

Comment: Thank you for your reply, helped a lot! See the answer below for my edited code and some further questions if you have time.